# Why does a custom domain redirect to herokuapp.com?

Tags: heroku, ghost

According to [this Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) we can allow a Heroku app hosted at `myapp.herokuapp.com` to be accessed with a custom domain `myapp.com`.

I have added the follow records to my GoDaddy DNS Zone File:

```
A (Host)
Host        Points To                    TTL
--------------------------------------------------
@           50.63.202.1                  1/2 Hour


CName (Alias)
Host        Points To                    TTL
--------------------------------------------------
email       email.secureserver.net       1/2 Hour
ftp         @                            1/2 Hour
www         myapp.herokuapp.com          1/2 Hour
```

Normally the A record points to a server. In this case Heroku doesn't provide an IP address for its cloud applications, and apparently CNAME is enough.

Navigating to `www.myapp.com` or `myapp.com` redirects to `https://myapp.herokuapp.com`. However, navigating to `http://www.myapp.com/blog/post/1` (any address not the homepage) will stay with the `www.myapp.com` domain, and clicking links is OK -- Except when clicking a link to the homepage we are redirected to the `myapp.herokuapp.com` address.

How can it be set up so the visitor does not see the herokuapp.com address unless visiting it with that address?

The output of heroku logs --tail --app myapp:

```
2016-03-11T01:13:49.756887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=vast-hamlet-33090.herokuapp.com request_id=6177aa6c-dc5f-4de5-a1c6-1ff8b1194849 fwd="24.17.117.236" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=304 bytes=181
2016-03-11T01:13:49.760014+00:00 app[web.1]: 24.17.117.236 - - [11/Mar/2016:01:13:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36"
```

It looks like the app never receives a request from www.myapp.com, but only myapp.herokuapp.com.

The output of heroku domains -a myapp:

```
=== myapp Heroku Domain
myapp.herokuapp.com

=== myapp Custom Domains
Domain Name         DNS Target
------------------  -------------------
www.myapp.com       myapp.herokuapp.com
myapp.com           myapp.herokuapp.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case using Ghost, updating the HEROKU_URL in the Ghost configuration to 'http://www.myapp.com' fixed this error. I thought I had this set up, but I changed it to 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com' so I could access the admin panel, which wasn't accepting requests from URLs not HEROKU_URL.

I was also having a separate issue with Chrome automatically, helpfully-not-helpfully redirecting before the request hit the server, so the Node app received a request for myapp.herokuapp.com. I discovered this by trying to use another browser to access my app. I cleared the browser cookies and cache and myapp.com was no longer redirected in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you ! I overlooked that part, was too focused on the Domain part I didn't see the ENV variables ;)

Comment: @Stan Glad this helped you :)

Comment: To get Chrome to play nicely, I had to flush Chrome's DNS cache (https://superuser.com/a/203702/252083) and sockets, along with the OS's DNS cache. Did that enough times and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For newer version of Ghost (3.x) while using the `https://github.com/SNathJr/ghost-on-heroku` deploy script, I updated the APP_PUBLIC_URL to use `http://example.com`.

Also I set a page rule in Cloudflare to use `http://*example.com/*` with the setting: `Always use HTTPS`

Answer (score 0):

To follow up in a later date. I had the same issue.
Using Heroku + Cloudflare + Custom domain. Andrei Erdoss answer works.

https in APP_PUBLIC_URL will cause 301 redirects.

---

For newer version of Ghost (3.x) while using the https://github.com/SNathJr/ghost-on-heroku deploy script, I updated the APP_PUBLIC_URL to use http://example.com.

Also I set a page rule in Cloudflare to use http://*example.com/* with the setting: Always use HTTPS

---